# Which actively maintained fork of slickgrid should we choose?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

We've been using slick grid for one of our packages. Unfortunately, looks like the [slick grid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) is not being actively maintained, which is really sad because it isn't **officially** compatible with anything newer than jQuery 1.7.

Is there an actively maintained fork of SlickGrid? Or a good alternative to this library?

According to that repo, slick grid is being actively used here by Stackoverflow.

Comment: While the maintenance of the original repo of SlickGrid is somewhat slowed down, I'm using SlickGrid with jQuery 2.1.4 flawlessly. Also you can find [fiddles](https://jsfiddle.net/yudhir/31bozsge/10/) that are for example using jQuery 1.9.1...

Answer (score 6):

You could try the following fork: https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid which has had updates recently (29th November).

The fork is accompanied by the following message:

> "This aims to be a viable alternative master repo while MLeibman is
>   busy. It builds on the current state of the mleibman/SlickGrid master
>   branch, keeping libraries up to date and applying small, safe core
>   patches and enhancements without turning into a personalised build."

Comment: This is the fork we ultimately decided to stick with.  Thanks for sharing!